# Send data from the server to a GPS device

Tags: c#, gps, gprs

this is my first question here, after searching and reading through many places I have not choice but to ask.
I have a C# application that receives data from a GPS device and stored in a database, I need now is to send a string that contains commands which the device should be interpreted.
This device connects to the Internet over GPRS, I haven't idea how to send this packet over TCP over GPRS because the IP is dynamic.

I hope any suggestions or ideas on how to solve this.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it the other way around - the device should poll the server for instructions. Just make sure the server is accessible.

Answer (score 0):

As you have specified that you have developed a C# application to read the GPS data through GPRS that means you are running C# application on a public/static IP.
Nwo as soon as you get a request from the GPRS client, you get the DHCP IP address of the remote endpoint too. 
Once you have that endpoint and socket open, you can transmit any data to the GPS device back.

Assuming that your GPS device is having some microcontroller to drive the GSM/GPRS modem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make an assumption here that the 'Device' is some kind of mobile phone connected to a standard GSM network?

If it is, then the short version of the story is "Forget it" even if the IP wasn't dynamic, you simply wouldn't be talking to the IP of your device, you'd actually be talking to the IP address of your providers GGSN, and for a standard consumer connection this is going to be where the buck stops.

Now that said, IF you have the budget, and all your devices (Assuming multiple ones) are with the same carrier, then you can approach the carrier and request a dedicated APN (Access point name) essentially what this is , is the mobile network equivalent of a DNS record, or at least similar enough to use that analogy anyway.

When you set up your data connection on your device you may recall having to enter something like 'pp.vodafone.com' or 'INGhub411.o2-uk.inbound' we'll this is your actual APN, and if you have a custom one they your devices can be set up so that the IP the presents itself at the GGSN actually has a static route back to the individual device in the suppliers GSM network.

As a general rule of thumb however on consumer grade connections this is not enabled and hence there is no ingress available to the individual device.

As zmbq says, the ONLY option you have is for the device to keep polling the server on a regular basis, and yes unfortunately that is going to be very unforgiving on the battery.

of course there is one other way of approaching this, and that's to have the device open a socket directly to your server then keep that socket open.  Once the socket is open, 2 way communication can be performed across the link, unfortunately your going to also have to write all the code to manage this connection including, but not limited to monitoring the connection to make sure it's still open and re-establishing it if it's not, something which is incredibly important on a mobile device.